# Bad File Descriptor error when setting non-blocking on a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm new to boost and I've been trying out boost::asio. The problem is I always get an "Bad File Descriptor" error/exception when setting some options (I need to make it non-blocking). Even this here fails:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main( )
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  tcp::socket socket( io_service );
  boost::asio::socket_base::non_blocking_io option(true);

  socket.io_control( option );

  return 0;
}
```

During run-time this pops up:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  Bad file descriptor
```

Which is getting really frustrating as I've tried everything. OS is Linux x64 if it matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You invoked the socket constructor that [does not open](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket.html) the `socket`. You could use one of the other overloads that open the `socket` prior to invoking `socket::io_control()`, or open the `socket` explicitly.

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I needed to set my option in the handler function that I passed to my async_accept call.